# Disable Safari's bookmark caching

Tags: bookmarks, safari

I need to somehow disable Safari's bookmark caching.

When I visit a page of a lecturer of mine that I've bookmarked before for easy access, Safari shows me the cached version it has; not the fresh one.

As a workaround, revisiting the bookmarked pages is an option but frankly it defeats the whole purpose of bookmarking which is very annoying.

I've tried resetting the Safari cache but with no help eventually.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can disable Safari's cache completely by going to the Develop menu (turn it on in the Advanced tab of Safari's preferences) and choosing 'Disable Caches'. Since you added information in your question here is a possible solution for you. To disable a current session (for the website you are on) do this:
To disable the cache for the session (requires developer menu to be enabled; go to "Preferences", pick the "Advanced" tab, then click "Show Develop menu in menu bar"):
Click "Develop", then click "Disable Caches".

Comment: You can hold down shift to reload the page without cache, FWIW. You also may want to get in touch with whoever maintains the page; it sounds like the cache headers (metadata that tells browsers how long to cache things) that their page is sending aren't right.

Comment: Getting in touch is a great solution but unfortunately I don't think my lecturers will do anything about since they're lazy about this kind of stuff. Also I'd no luck with "shift+refresh" before as well. The page is still the same after it.

Comment: Have you tried opening the page in another browser? Maybe it's just cached on the server.

Comment: I think you're right. Google Chrome showed me the exact same stuff even though I refreshed it as well.